# PHP and MYSQL : Make a quiz type paper style template using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreach, laravel-5

I have a query result with the set of rows containing topics and question and options for that question. I would like form a question frame question and if its topic ...then questions under the topic .and options under the questions. For example the data set as below

```
id   | name           | qType  | is_optional | order | type     | topic_id | qid | options
__________________________________________________________________________________________

13   | Test Topic  1  | NULL   | 0            | 0    | topic    | 0       | NULL | NULL
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
14   | Tp 1 Question  | text   | 1            | 0    | question | 13      | NULL | NULL
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
19   | Tp 2 Question  | text   | 1            | 0    | question | 18      | NULL | NULL
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
15   | Tp 2 Question  | text   | 1            | 1    | question | 13      | NULL | Option 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
15   | Tp 1 Question  | text   | 1            | 1    | question | 13      | NULL | Option 2
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
16   | Question       | text   | 1            | 1    | question | 0       | NULL | NULL
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
18   | Topic 2        | text   | 1            | 5    | topic    | 0       | NULL | NULL
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Expected result to form : It is based on order

```
1.Topic 1 
   1.Tp 1 Question 
   2.Tp 1 Question 
       1.Option 1
       2.Option 2
2.Question
3.Topic 2 
   1.Tp 2 Question 
   2.Tp 2 Question 
       1.Option 1
       2.Option 2
```

My query :

```
SELECT t.*,t1.* 
                FROM(SELECT  q.id,q.question as name,rv.code as qType,q.is_optional,q.order,q.type,q.topic_id
                    FROM pit_tc_questions as q              
                     WHERE q.template_id = $templateID AND q.is_deleted = 0 AND q.is_active = 1 ) as t 
                LEFT JOIN (SELECT q1.id as qid,o.options 
                            FROM pit_tc_questions as q1      

                            WHERE q1.template_id = $templateID AND q1.is_deleted = 0 AND q1.is_active = 1
                            AND o.is_deleted = 0 AND o.is_active = 1 ORDER BY o.order ASC) as t1 ON t1.qid = t.id     
                ORDER BY t.order ASC
```

And My PHP COde :

```
$collection = collect($questions);
$grouped    = $collection->groupBy('topic_id');  
foreach ($grouped as $keys => $values) {
    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        if($key == 0){
            $result[$value->order]['question'] = $value;    
        } 
        $result[$value->order]['options'][] = $value;                             
    }                      
}
```

Any idea ???

Expecting :

```
Array [0] {
    [topic] => 'Topic Question'
    [question] => [0] { name => Question 1}
               [1] { name => Question 2} 
               [options] => [0] { options => Option 1}
                            [1] { options => Option 2}    
}
Array [1] {
    [topic] => 'Topic Question'
    [question] => ''
}
Array [2] {
    [topic]    => 'Topic Question'
    [question] => [0] { name => Question 1}
                  [1] { name => Question 2} 
                  [options]  => [0] { options => Option 1}
                                [1] { options => Option 2}

}
```

What i'm getting is :

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
                (
                    [items:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 13
                                    [name] => Test Topic
                                    [qType] => 
                                    [is_optional] => 0
                                    [order] => 0
                                    [type] => topic
                                    [topic_id] => 0
                                    [qid] => 
                                    [options] => 
                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 16
                                    [name] => 

Stand Alone Question 1


                                    [qType] => text
                                    [is_optional] => 1
                                    [order] => 1
                                    [type] => question
                                    [topic_id] => 0
                                    [qid] => 
                                    [options] => 
                                )

                            [2] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 18
                                    [name] => Test Topic 2
                                    [qType] => 
                                    [is_optional] => 0
                                    [order] => 5
                                    [type] => topic
                                    [topic_id] => 0
                                    [qid] => 
                                    [options] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

            [13] => Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
                (
                    [items:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 14
                                    [name] => 

Topic 1 : Text Question


                                    [qType] => text
                                    [is_optional] => 1
                                    [order] => 0
                                    [type] => question
                                    [topic_id] => 13
                                    [qid] => 
                                    [options] => 
                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 15
                                    [name] => 

Topic 2 : Mulitple Question


                                    [qType] => multiple
                                    [is_optional] => 1
                                    [order] => 1
                                    [type] => question
                                    [topic_id] => 13
                                    [qid] => 15
                                    [options] => Option 1
                                )

                            [2] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 15
                                    [name] => 

Topic 2 : Mulitple Question


                                    [qType] => multiple
                                    [is_optional] => 1
                                    [order] => 1
                                    [type] => question
                                    [topic_id] => 13
                                    [qid] => 15
                                    [options] => Option 2
                                )

                        )

                )

            [18] => Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
                (
                    [items:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 19
                                    [name] => 

Topic 2 : Question


                                    [qType] => text
                                    [is_optional] => 1
                                    [order] => 0
                                    [type] => question
                                    [topic_id] => 18
                                    [qid] => 
                                    [options] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: What's the exact problem so I can better understand this?

Comment: You've shown what you're expecting, but not what you're getting.